# Angular 13 Directive viewContainerRef.createComponent pass object to created component

Tags: angular, angular13

The code below with Dynamically create a component in Angular 13

The Directive:

```
import { Directive, Input, ViewContainerRef, Type } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appLoader]'
})
export class LoaderDirective {

  @Input() appLoader!: Type<any>;

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.appLoader);
  }

}
```

app.component.html

```
<div [appLoader]="component"></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
component = MyComponent
```

I also need to pass an object into the component that's created which is some extra information which will be used by the created component.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine you directive can be some like

```
export class LoaderDirective {

  @Input() appLoader!: Type<any>;
  @Input() arg:any;  //<--you pass as arg any object

  //you need inject ComponentFactoryResolver
  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
              private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    //first you "create" a component
    const component=this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.appLoader)
    //in componentRef you get a instance of the component
    const componentRef=this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(component);

    //you can access to the component using componentRef.instance
    //e.g. componentRef.instance.someMethod()
    //     componentRef.instance.prop="what-ever"

    //I choose use the object pass in the "arg" Input
    Object.keys(this.arg).forEach(x=>{
      componentRef.instance[x]=this.arg[x]
    })
  }
```

You use like

```
<div [appLoader]="component" [arg]="{name:'Angular'}"></div>
```

See a [fool stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-thsnng?file=src%2Fapp%2Floader.directive.ts)

Comment: In Angular 13 you no longer need to use resolveComponentFactory to create a component with the new api

Comment: I didn't know, thanks,

Comment: This would have worked in prior versions of angular but since ComponentFactoryResolver is deprecated you have to use ViewContainerRef.